# Passing a variable-length argument to a function without checking the length of it?

Tags: c

Could I pass a variable-length argument to a function without checking the length of it!
That is Could I make a List or something others , and pass it to a variable-length argument function.
I know we can us va_list to implement the function;
But now,
We get a argument list, and we need count the length, and then maybe we should define a number of variables， and pass them,
Could we make it more convenient?

Answer (score 1):

You can always add a special "marker" argument at the end of the list indicating that it is finished, like `NULL`

```
char **args = { "one", "two", NULL }
function( args );
...
void function ( char **args ) {
  char *p;
  int i = 0;
  p = args[i];
  while( p != NULL) {
    ...
    i++;
    p = args[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't based on var-args.

Comment: Nope, it is not. But it works, and I saw it in action many times.

Comment: Also, this won't compile.  `args[i]` is of type `char`; you can't assign it to `p`.

Comment: Actually， it's always used in the main().To a great extent, it depends on the implement of the fuction itself. How about given an API?

Comment: @SnailTang: in `main` you get the number of arguments explicitly, and as I understood, you want to avoid counting the arguments

Comment: @Jakub M.:Yeah, but it's not the point. Maybe , I should point out that the var-args fuction may has been implemented